# How can I deploy Jekyll site from github repo to my ftp?

Tags: github, build, jekyll, workflow, github-actions

I have a custom Jekyll site which is working fine on local.

I would like to deploy my builded site to my hosting environment. Via FTP with github actions is working fine with this: https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action

This is the FTP workflow:

```
on: push
name: Publish Website
jobs:
  FTP-Deploy-Action:
    name: FTP-Deploy-Action
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2.1.0
      with:
        fetch-depth: 2
    - name: FTP-Deploy-Action
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@3.1.1
      with:
        ftp-server: ${{ secrets.FTP_HOST }}
        ftp-username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USER }}
        ftp-password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
        local-dir: _site
        git-ftp-args: --changed-only
```

I tried with the `_site` folder and and action is run with every commit when the _site is not ignored.

So the best, If I am not comitting the `_site` page, that will do the GitHub server. I found this action: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/jekyll-actions

My test workflow:

```
on: push
name: Testing the GitHub Pages building
    
jobs:
  jekyll:
    runs-on: ubuntu-16.04
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    # Use GitHub Actions' cache to shorten build times and decrease load on servers
    - uses: actions/cache@v1
      with:
        path: vendor/bundle
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-gems-${{ hashFiles('**/Gemfile.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-gems-

    # Standard usage
    - uses:  humarci/jekyll-action@1.0.0
    
    # FTP maybe from here
```

Comment: So from my understanding, you are trying to use GitHub actions to clone the repo, build the site and then upload the finished `_site` folder to a web server via FTP?

Comment: Yes. Everyting is in the github repo. I would like just build it and then upload the result via ftp to a server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I currently use, which I found from [The World According to Mike Blog](https://mikeconroy.com/2020/04/automating-jekyll-deployments-github-actions/).

This uses ncftp which allows you to upload files via ftp easily.

```
name: Build & Upload Site
# Run on pushes to the master branch
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: '2.7'
    # Install the gems in the gemfile & install ncftp
    - name: Setup Environment.
      run: |
        bundle install
        sudo apt-get install -y ncftp
    
    # Build the site
    - name: Build Site with Jekyll.
      run: JEKYLL_ENV=production bundle exec jekyll build
    
    # Looks kind of complicated but just uploads the content of _site folder to the ftp server. It does not upload the _site folder itself.
    - name: Upload site to FTP.
      env: 
        ftp_location: ${{ secrets.FTP_LOCATION }} # Pass in required secrets.
        ftp_username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
        ftp_password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }} 
      run: |
        ncftpput -R -v -u "$ftp_username" -p "$ftp_password" $ftp_location / _site/*
```

Comment: Very helpful. As an addition, I had to figure out how to make this work for SFTP which ncftpput doesn't support. I ended up using LFTP and create a known_hosts file in the GH Actions script. See my code here: https://github.com/DavidSlr/portfolio/blob/main/.github/workflows/jekyll-build-deploy.yml